# "no versions of image available" for "docker-image"

Tags: concourse

I created a docker image and uploaded to my internal artifactory for concourse pipeline.
However, when I execute the job, error "no versions of image available" is printed.
I don't know how could I trace the problem

What did I get wrong? Anyone can help?

```
- task: build
  config:
    platform: linux
    image_resource:
      type: docker-image
      source:
        repository: artifact.com/oocl/test_iamge
        tag: "latest"
    run:
      path: sh
      args:
      - -exc
      - |
        ping artifact.com -c 5
```

Comment: How did you build your docker image? Did you add a version to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No versions available indicates that something in general seems to be odd with your configuration regarding the image or the image itself is not accessible.

Have you tried running your docker image locally first? `docker run artifact.com/oocl/test_iamge`

Do you require credentials to receive the image from the server? -> checkout the example here https://concourse-ci.org/running-tasks.html

```
image_resource:
  type: docker-image
  source:
    repository: my.local.registry:8080/my/image
    insecure_registries: ["my.local.registry:8080"]
    username: myuser
    password: mypass
    email: x@x.com
```

Comment: Yes, problem solved after added those configurations. Thanks,